# how to get all vm statsus using azure cli.?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

how to get status of all VM in Azure which is not using from last X hours and how we can get another resource status using azure cli.

Comment: define: "not using"?

Comment: I have posted an answer to get the VM status and alternative query using powershell to get the VM details and status. But please ensure to add the effort , code sample you have tried and docs you have referred before posting.

Answer (score 0):

For getting VM status in powershell you can run a query like below which will give you the Display status of your VM.

```
$RG = "RG01"
$VM = "ADFS"

((Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $RG -Name $VM -Status).Statuses[1]).code
```

in Azure CLI , you can run the following command:

```
az vm get-instance-view --name vmName --resource-group resourceGroupName --query instanceView.statuses[1] --output table
```

[image]

Below query will return the complete data of your VM

```
Get-AzureRmVM -Name CM01 -ResourceGroupName RG -Status


ResourceGroupName       : RG
Name                    : CM01
Disks[0]                :
  Name                  : CM01
  Statuses[0]           :
    Code                : ProvisioningState/succeeded
    Level               : Info
    DisplayStatus       : Provisioning succeeded
    Time                : 18/08/2016 08:10:20
VMAgent                 :
  VmAgentVersion        : 2.7.1198.778
  ExtensionHandlers[0]  :
    Type                : Microsoft.Azure.RecoveryServices.VMSnapshot
    TypeHandlerVersion  : 1.0.10.0
    Status              :
      Code              : ProvisioningState/succeeded
      Level             : Info
      DisplayStatus     : Ready
      Message           : Plugin enabled (name:     Microsoft.Azure.RecoveryServices.VMSnapshot, version: 1.0.10.0).
  ExtensionHandlers[1]  :
    Type                : Microsoft.Compute.BGInfo
    TypeHandlerVersion  : 1.2.2
    Status              :
      Code              : ProvisioningState/succeeded
      Level             : Info
      DisplayStatus     : Ready
      Message           : Plugin enabled (name: Microsoft.Compute.BGInfo, version: 1.2.2).
  Statuses[0]           :
    Code                : ProvisioningState/succeeded
    Level               : Info
    DisplayStatus       : Ready
    Message             : GuestAgent is running and accepting new configurations.
    Time                : 18/08/2016 14:52:59
Statuses[0]             :
  Code                  : ProvisioningState/succeeded
  Level                 : Info
  DisplayStatus         : Provisioning succeeded
  Time                  : 18/08/2016 12:14:04
Statuses[1]             :
  Code                  : PowerState/running
  Level                 : Info
  DisplayStatus         : VM running
```